# Write a limited number of characters then return to the line in Perl and do not cut the last word

Tags: perl

I have a character string in an array and I want to write it to a file. The problem is I need to write for a number of characters limited to 100 then I must return to the the line and finish the content of the sentence. Then if I happen to 100 characters again I return to the line until I finish my chain content in the table.

Comment: Your question is hard to read and even harder to understand. [Edit it to improve it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10106418/edit): Add punctuation. Give example input and output. Show the code you already have written in an attempt to solve the problem, exactly point out the parts with which you are having problems without our help.

Comment: Please show some examples of your array and the format you want the output. If you have an array does that mean there are multiple strings?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Text::Wrap`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aWrap) module is likely to do what you want, and is a part of core Perl meaning you don't have to install it.

This program reads the text from the `DATA` pseudo-handle and reformats it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Wrap;

my @text = <DATA>;
chomp @text;

$Text::Wrap::columns = 100;
print Text::Wrap::wrap '', '', @text;

__DATA__
"Text::Wrap::wrap()" is a very simple paragraph formatter. It formats a
single paragraph at a time by breaking lines at word boundaries.
Indentation is controlled for the first line ($initial_tab) and all
subsequent lines ($subsequent_tab) independently. Please note:
$initial_tab and $subsequent_tab are the literal strings that will be
used: it is unlikely you would want to pass in a number.

Text::Wrap::fill() is a simple multi-paragraph formatter. It formats
each paragraph separately and then joins them together when it's done.
It will destroy any whitespace in the original text. It breaks text into
paragraphs by looking for whitespace after a newline. In other respects
it acts like wrap().

Both "wrap()" and "fill()" return a single string.
```

**output**

```
"Text::Wrap::wrap()" is a very simple paragraph formatter. It formats a single paragraph at a time
by breaking lines at word boundaries. Indentation is controlled for the first line ($initial_tab)
and all subsequent lines ($subsequent_tab) independently. Please note: $initial_tab and
$subsequent_tab are the literal strings that will be used: it is unlikely you would want to pass in
a number.  Text::Wrap::fill() is a simple multi-paragraph formatter. It formats each paragraph
separately and then joins them together when it's done. It will destroy any whitespace in the
original text. It breaks text into paragraphs by looking for whitespace after a newline. In other
respects it acts like wrap().  Both "wrap()" and "fill()" return a single string.
```

Comment: really tanks this module is very useful but i have to add a caractere before chaque ligne returned any one have a idea??

Comment: @user1236482, Comme ceci: `my $wrapped = Text::Wrap::wrap(...); $wrapped =~ s/^X//gm; print $wrapped;` ["Chaque ligne" == "each line"]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like [Text::Reform](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aReform) or [Text::Autoformat](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aAutoformat).